# Election comment links

Tags: script, elections

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts

Makes the datestamp into a comment link for election comments. Also fixes the issue in the responses tab (linked above).

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/ElectionCommentLinks.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/ElectionCommentLinks.user.js)

### Usage

Hit tab in an edit box. Instead of defocusing, the literal ta will be inserted into the textarea.